# How to fix Allocations problem?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I see this problem in instruments tool but dont know where is the problem. There are no leaks reports

when I followed the links I found some problems (image 2&3&4) is these a leak or what? I think I am doing the same mistakes everywhere in the code..but dont know what

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try to manually release the label after adding it as subview if it's possible, I don't see why it has to be autoreleased. If you need a reference to it, then you could just release it in your dealloc function. Please tell why it's autoreleased and I can try to make a full answer.

Comment: @Samuli Lehtonen ur right I will make it release. about other things? especially I have alloc problems with the navigation controller, I see huge memory increase in every push even I nillify the views in viewwilldisappear

Comment: You should check if your dealloc method is called when you pop viewcontroller(aka go back in hierarchy).

Comment: @Samuli Lehtonen yes dealloc is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of leaks from looking at your code:

- the activityIndicator, you never release it.
- self.conn = [NSURLConnection alloc]... It will cause a leak, take out the "self" behind conn. (presuming your setter is retaining)
- UILabel, you never release it.

Try that and let me know.

Comment: tnx, Im confused, conn is autoreleased so why would self.conn = [NSURLConnection alloc].. leaks? retain will be 2 and then 1 again after pool? UILabel is also autoreleased

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something is allocating tons of Objective-C strings.  Click the arrow next to the "CFString" category name to see what's calling the alloc function on NSString.